# handle state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button inside map , the map is running 3 times , so  3 button is there , when clicking it should change the state to true or false to show or hide the heading text , but when I am clicking on one button it is displaying all the three text .  why is it so? and how to handle this so that clicking on one button should not trigger all the button

```
 class Example extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super()
   this.state={
   arr:[ 1,2,3 ],
   show : false
  }
 this.handleShow=this.handleShow.bind(this)
  }

handleShow(){
 this.setState ({
 show:!this.state.show
  })
  }

 render(){
  this.state.arr.map(()=>console.log("niketh"))
   return(<div>
  {this.state.arr.map(()=>

 <div>
   <button onClick={this.handleShow}>click me</button>
   {this.state.show?<h1>this is text inside map</h1>
   :false
   }
   </div>
 )} 
</div>
)

 }}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Something like this

Comment: Code? Anything concrete to work off of other than a paragraph?

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: I will edit it with code

Comment: If you have three different buttons, you have to have three different values that represent visibility, each for the text block that corresponds with a certain button.

Comment: What if array have 100 items and more ,Can you give an example .

Comment: You have unclosed `h1` tags, also `this.state.arr.map(...)` should be in brackets `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of things.  For one, you you have attached the same event handler to all of the buttons, so the same logic is getting fired when any of the buttons are clicked.  And you only have one state field to handle whether or not to show the text, even though you have 3 text fields. Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, you can fix this by doing a couple of things.  Use an inline method for your event handler and have multiple fields to handle the state of the visible text.

**Update** now sets up state array based on arbitrary sized array

I didn't check this, but it could be fixed doing something like this:

```
class Example extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  const initialData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  super()
  this.state={
  arr:initialData,
  // generate array of with the same size of 
  show : initialData.map(() => false)
 }

 this.handleShow=this.handleShow.bind(this)
}
// pass parameter to show which visbile state to change 
handleShow(i){
 this.setState ({
 show[i]:!this.state.show[i]
  })
 }

 render(){
  return(
  <div>
  {/* 
  map callback actually has three params:
  element, index, array
  using the index here to know which one is being called
  */}
  this.state.arr.map((x, i)=>
  {
    {/* making an inline event handler taht will call handle show */}
  <button onClick={ (evt) => this.handleShow(i) }> click me <button>
     {this.state.show[i]? <h1> I am text <h1> : false }
    }
   </div>
             )
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion @John Teague , but what if the array items is unknown ,or arr  is very large

Comment: That sample did not access the array, just the indexes.  If it is a long array you should page your results.  Not because of the logic. Just to keep your page size maintainable. :)

Comment: hey @John Teague , what does it mean , page your results ? Can you explain more clearly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination#Pagination_in_electronic_display

Answer (score 0):

thanks to **@John Teague** for suggesting this and
here is the working link http://codepen.io/Zedak/pen/RpgRoQ?editors=0011

```
class Example extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super()
   this.state={
  arr:[ 1,2,3 ],
  show : [false,false,false]
  }
this.handleShow=this.handleShow.bind(this)
}

handleShow(e,i){
  this.state.show[i]=!this.state.show[i]
  this.setState({
 show:this.state.show
 }) 

}

render(){

  return(<div>
  {this.state.arr.map((x,i)=>

 <div>
 <button onClick={ (evt) => this.handleShow(evt,i) }> click me </button>
 {this.state.show[i]? <h1> I am text inside map</h1> 
                            : false 
 }
   </div>
 )} 
  </div>
   )

 }}

 ReactDOM.render(<Example/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

but still I am wondering ,how to deal ,if array is large or unknown.

Comment: I forked your codepen to show how you can set up your state array based on an arbitrary sized array.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpOmxQ?editors=0011